# convert character linestring to geometry in sf

Tags: r, r-sf

Basic question, how do I convert type `character` `LINESTRING` variable to a `geometry` type in `sf` and then separately, separate the two coordinates into different variables. E.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
df <- structure(list(geometry = c("LINESTRING (-85.76 38.34, -85.72 38.38)", 
                            "LINESTRING (-85.46 38.76, -85.42 38.76)", 
                            "LINESTRING (-85.89 38.31, -85.85 38.32)"
), var1 = c(4, 5, 6
), var2 = c(1, 2, 3
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
df
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   geometry                                 var1  var2
#   <chr>                                   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 LINESTRING (-85.76 38.34, -85.72 38.38)     4     1
# 2 LINESTRING (-85.46 38.76, -85.42 38.76)     5     2
# 3 LINESTRING (-85.89 38.31, -85.85 38.32)     6     3
```

**Desired output:**

```
final
#                     geometry   start_lon start_lat end_lon end_lat var1 var2
# -85.76, -85.72, 38.34, 38.38      -85.76     38.34  -85.72   38.38    4    1
# -85.46, -85.42, 38.76, 38.76      -85.46     38.76  -85.42   38.76    5    2
# -85.89, -85.85, 38.31, 38.32      -85.89     38.31  -85.85   38.32    6    3


#so I can quickly plot lines between points
plot(final[, "var1"])
```

I thought some combination like  `final <- st_as_sf(df) %>% st_geometry(geometry)` would convert it but I cant figure it out. Perhaps `sfheaders` is useful here?

**EDIT**

I want an `sf` type solution and not to manually extract coordinates.

Any suggestions?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`library(sf)` can read Well-known Text direclty, if you tell it to using the `wkt =` argument. This gives you your `sf` object.

```
sf <- sf::st_as_sf( df, wkt = "geometry" )
sf
# Simple feature collection with 3 features and 2 fields
# geometry type:  LINESTRING
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: -85.89 ymin: 38.31 xmax: -85.42 ymax: 38.76
# CRS:            NA
#                         geometry var1 var2
# 1 LINESTRING (-85.76 38.34, -...    4    1
# 2 LINESTRING (-85.46 38.76, -...    5    2
# 3 LINESTRING (-85.89 38.31, -...    6    3
```

Then there are many ways you can get the coordinates out and reshape them. Here I'm using `sfheaders` to convert the sf object to a long data.frame, then using `library(data.table)` to reshape it.

```r
library(sfheaders)
library(data.table)

dt <- sfheaders::sf_to_df( sf, fill = TRUE )
setDT( dt )

## In this example, every 2nd row is to be made into new columns

odds <- 1:nrow(dt) %% 2 == 1
evens <- !odds

dt <- dt[odds][
  dt[evens, .(end_lon = x, end_lat = y, linestring_id)]
  , on = "linestring_id"
]

setnames( dt, c("x","y"), c("start_lon", "start_lat"))

dt
#    var1 var2 sfg_id linestring_id start_lon start_lat end_lon end_lat
# 1:    4    1      1             1    -85.76     38.34  -85.72   38.38
# 2:    5    2      2             2    -85.46     38.76  -85.42   38.76
# 3:    6    3      3             3    -85.89     38.31  -85.85   38.32
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the mentioned package but using regex we can do something like

```
gsub("[^0-9\\.\\s-]", "", df$geometry, perl= TRUE)
```

For the desired output we can use

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(df, do.call("rbind.data.frame", lapply(strsplit(gsub("[^0-9\\.\\s-]", "", df$geometry, perl= TRUE), " "), function(i) as.numeric(i[2:length(i)]))))
df <- df[ , c(1, 4:7, 2, 3)]
names(df) <- c("geometry", "start_lon", "start_lat", "end_lon", "end_lat", "var1", "var2")
```

What it does: `gsub` extracts the characters you are interested in, `strsplit` splits the strings after every space, the part in `lapply` is to drop each first space and to convert to numeric and `do.call` binds all to a dataframe. Finally, we change column order and name the columns.

Comment: thanks but I'm looking for an `sf` type solution. Your approach doesn't answer my main question, how do I convert character variable `geometry` to type `geometry` to plot with `sf`.

Comment: @user I am not sure what your question is about I think. In general, you can change class with `class(df$geometry) <- "geometry"`. Also, I am not sure how `plot(final[, "var1"])` can plot lines because the variable contains only one number per row. Maybe someone other can help

Comment: solution i was looking for is above, thanks for the help